# Visual Studio throws "undeclared identifier" from predefined string macro

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, preprocessor

I have the following preprocessed macro defined under **C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options**:

```
/D NV_WORKING_DIRECTORY="C:/foo"
```

An image from the project settings:

[image]

I have the following code:

```
std::string path = NV_WORKING_DIRECTORY;
```

When I compile I get this error:

> 'C': undeclared identifier.

Weirdly, with certain strings the code works. For example if I do `/D NV_WORKING_DIRECTORY="foo"` everything is good. But `"garbage"` for some reason gives the same error.

Hardcoding`#define NV_WORKING_DIRECTORY "C:/foo/"` makes the code above work, but because I need a *global* macro that is not an option.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? This is a brand new project, and I have not messed around with anything yet.

Comment: Any chance you use single backslashes? Image doesn’t load for me but \ doesn’t work. Instead you can use \\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `/D` in the **C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options**, the value is expected to be wrapped in a string.
E.g. the following means the value of `XXX` will be `YYY`:

```
/D XXX="YYY"
```

Therefore if you need the value of the preprocessor definition to contain the quotes, you need to add and escape them:

```
/D NV_WORKING_DIRECTORY="\"C:/foo/\""
```

Alternatively you can add the `NV_WORKING_DIRECTORY` defintion under **C/C++ -> Preprocessor Definitions**.
There you can simply put the string value that you need:

```
NV_WORKING_DIRECTORY="C:/foo/"
```

Comment: My code works now! Thank you very much for your help and explanation